# How to debug Angular JavaScript Code

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs, browser

I am working on a proof of concept using Angular JavaScript.

How to debug the Angular JavaScript code in different browsers (Firefox and Chrome) ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**1. Chrome**

For debugging AngularJS in **Chrome** you can use **AngularJS Batarang**.
(From recent reviews on the plugin it seems like AngularJS Batarang is no longer being maintained. Tested in various versions of Chrome and it does not work.)

Here is the the link for a description and demo:
[Introduction of Angular JS Batarang](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/introducing-angularjs-batarang.html)

Download Chrome plugin from here: [Chrome plugin for debugging AngularJS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)

You can also use ng-inspect for debugging angular.

**2. Firefox**

For **Firefox** with the help of **Firebug** you can debug the code.

Also use this Firefox Add-Ons: [AngScope: Add-ons for Firefox](https://github.com/kosprov/AngScope) (Not official extension by AngularJS Team)

**3. Debugging AngularJS**

Check the Link: [Debugging AngularJS](https://www.newline.co/ng-book/p/Debugging-AngularJS/)

Comment: shame it doesn't really work. I wish the guy would start maintaining the thing cuz it's a great idea and has a lot of potential

Comment: @AskQuestion Looks like Batarang is no longer supported. This answer should be removed

Comment: The Angular team (mostly @btford) still supports Batarang, but it doesn't appear to be a priority on their list, since they are all heads in on the next AngularJS 2.0 release. Look into the `ng-inspect` if Batarang is giving you headaches.

Comment: assuming that batarang is working properly, no additional context is added to the angular.js errors in the console and the 'AngularJS' tab doesn't help either.

Comment: The key her is that Batarang doesn't help you debug Angular... It helps you fix bugs in angular... it is sooo not a debugger...no brakepoints no stepping though code...

Comment: How to know the exact line throwing error? It always show error only in angular.js but not in module or view

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan : Use F12 then Script and click the Configuration button, and then click Format JavaScript. This way you will simply find the the line with Red mark in which you are getting error.

Comment: @VaibhavJain I am using Mac

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan : ok. Try this -> on the mac version you have a Developer menu ("Develop"), at the mac this menu is shown via the preferences > advanced > show develop menu, and there you can view items such as "Start debugging javascript". For your reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUvsnDhFL2w

Comment: @vaibhav-jain the issue isn't in using the console error log to find the source of the error, the issue is that the source of the error is changed by angularjs so that it *can't* be known from the console where the error actually came from with out heavily debugging angularjs's own source code.

Answer (score 37):

IMHO, the most frustrating experience comes from getting / setting a value of a specific scope related to an visual element. I did a lot of breakpoints not only in my own code, but also in angular.js itself, but sometimes it is simply not the most effective way.
Although the methods below are very powerful, they are definitely considered to be bad practice if you actually use in production code, so use them wisely!

## Get a reference in console from a visual element

In many non-IE browsers, you can select an element by right clicking an element and clicking "Inspect Element". Alternatively you can also click on any element in Elements tab in Chrome, for example. The latest selected element will be stored in variable `$0` in console.

## Get a scope linked to an element

Depending on whether there exists a directive that creates an isolate scope, you can retrieve the scope by `angular.element($0).scope()` or `angular.element($0).isolateScope()` (use `$($0).scope()` if $ is enabled). This is exactly what you get when you are using the latest version of Batarang. If you are changing the value directly, remember to use `scope.$digest()` to reflect the changes on UI.

## $eval is evil

Not necessarily for debugging. `scope.$eval(expression)` is very handy when you want to quickly check whether an expression has the expected value.

## The missing prototype members of scope

The difference between `scope.bla` and `scope.$eval('bla')` is the former does not consider the prototypically inherited values. Use the snippet below to get the whole picture (you cannot directly change the value, but you can use `$eval` anyway!)

```
scopeCopy = function (scope) {
    var a = {}; 
    for (x in scope){ 
        if (scope.hasOwnProperty(x) && 
            x.substring(0,1) !== '$' && 
            x !== 'this') {
            a[x] = angular.copy(scope[x])
        }
    }
    return a
};

scopeEval = function (scope) {
    if (scope.$parent === null) {
        return hoho(scope)
    } else {
        return angular.extend({}, haha(scope.$parent), hoho(scope))
    }
};
```

Use it with `scopeEval($($0).scope())`.

## Where is my controller?

Sometimes you may want to monitor the values in `ngModel` when you are writing a directive. Use `$($0).controller('ngModel')` and you will get to check the `$formatters`, `$parsers`, `$modelValue`, `$viewValue` `$render` and everything.

Answer (score 13):

there is also $log that you can use! it makes use of your console in a way that you want it to work!

showing the error/warning/info the way your console shows you normally!

use this > [Document](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$log)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 11):

Despite the question is answered, it could be interesting to take a look at [ng-inspector](http://ng-inspector.org/)

Comment: I don't find AngularJS Batarang useful, ng-inspector seems to work nicely though.

Comment: Not available for Chrome anymore

Comment: Installed it on Chrome today. Works great, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Try ng-inspector.  Download the add-on for Firefox from the website http://ng-inspector.org/.  It is not available on the Firefox add on menu.

http://ng-inspector.org/ - website

http://ng-inspector.org/ng-inspector.xpi - Firefox Add-on﻿

Comment: Not available for Chrome anymore

Comment: Installed it on Chrome today. Works great, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately most of add-ons and browser extensions are just showing the values to you but they don't let you to edit scope variables or run angular functions. If you wanna change the $scope variables in browser console (in all browsers) then you can use jquery. If you load jQuery before AngularJS, angular.element can be passed a jQuery selector. So you could inspect the scope of a controller with

```
angular.element('[ng-controller="name of your controller"]').scope()
```

**Example:** 
You need to change value of $scope variable and see the result in the browser then just type in the browser console:

```
angular.element('[ng-controller="mycontroller"]').scope().var1 = "New Value";
angular.element('[ng-controller="mycontroller"]').scope().$apply();
```

You can see the changes in your browser immediately. The reason we used $apply() is: any scope variable updated from outside angular context won't update it binding, You need to run digest cycle after updating values of scope using `scope.$apply()` .

For observing a $scope variable value, you just need to call that variable.

**Example:**
You wanna see the value of $scope.var1 in the web console in Chrome or Firefox just type:

```
angular.element('[ng-controller="mycontroller"]').scope().var1;
```

The result will be shown in the console immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Add call to `debugger` where you intend to use it.

```
someFunction(){
  debugger;
}
```

In the `console` tab of your browser's web developer tools, issue `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();`

Visit or reload the page you intend to debug and see the debugger appear in your browser.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to work inside components for some reason.  The console seems to locate the break point at the point the component is created, but won't display the code that is actually executing.  At least not for me.  although you can view the value of variables that are scope.  If anybody knows how to get the debugger to display the actual code that is being stepped through advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
var rootEle = document.querySelector("html");
var ele = angular.element(rootEle);
```

**scope()**
We can fetch the $scope from the element (or its parent) by using the scope() method on the
element:

```
var scope = ele.scope();
```

**injector()**

```
var injector = ele.injector();
```

With this injector, we can then then instantiate any Angular object inside of our app, such as services,
other controllers, or any other object

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can add 'debugger' in your code and reload the app, which puts the breakpoint there and you can 'step over' , or run.

```
var service = {
user_id: null,
getCurrentUser: function() {
  debugger; // Set the debugger inside 
            // this function
  return service.user_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can debug using browsers built in developer tools.

1. open developer tools in browser and go to source tab.
2. open the file do you want to debug using Ctrl+P and search file name
3. add break point on a line ny clicking on left side of the code.
4. refresh the page.

There are lot of plugin available for debugging you can refer for using chrome plugin [Debug Angular Application using "Debugger for chrome" plugin](https://latestangular.blogspot.com/2018/07/debug-angular-application-using.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Code (Not Visual Studio) do  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Type Debugger for Chrome in the search bar, install it and enable it.

In your `launch.json` file add this config :

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/mypage.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/app/files",
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html (without sourcemaps)",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html"
        },
    ]
}
```

You must launch Chrome with remote debugging enabled in order for the extension to attach to it.

- Windows

Right click the Chrome shortcut, and select properties
In the "target" field, append --remote-debugging-port=9222
Or in a command prompt, execute /chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

- OS X

In a terminal, execute /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222

- Linux

In a terminal, launch google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222

[**Find More ===>**](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Since the add-ons don't work anymore, the most helpful set of tools I've found is using Visual Studio/IE because you can set breakpoints in your JS and inspect your data that way. Of course Chrome and Firefox have much better dev tools in general. Also, good ol' console.log() has been super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Angular Augury](https://augury.angular.io/) A Google Chrome Dev Tools extension for debugging Angular 2 and above applications.