# AngularJS ng-route redirect refreshes full page

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

i have the problem that AngularJS refreshes full Page and not only the ng-view

my config:

```
myApp.config(function($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
  //ROUTE
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'views/mainForm.html',
    controller : 'TabController'
  }).when('/login', {
    templateUrl : 'views/loginForm.html',
    controller : 'LoginController'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/',
  });
});
```

my index:

```
 <body>
<!--NAVBAR -->
<navbarform></navbarform>
<!--Login oder MainView -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="main">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i click on my Navbar button: {{username}} its not opening the dropdown. its refresh the full page...

what i`m doing wrong?

Comment: you must have link to `#` only which will refresh the page, show the dropdown link `Navbar button` please

Comment: If possible provide us plunker or fiddle because this code is not enough to think about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First Check :-

1. Was ng-app set ?
2. Is the controller TabController loaded ?
3. Checked for other JS error in the page.

After that :-

Debug using [Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782069/how-to-debug-angular-javascript-code) & [AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/).

And even after this issue is not resolved create a JSfiddle and post the link here.

Hope this helps.