# Debugging AngularJS in Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug a `$http` problem in our app and when I step into `$http.get` the debugger doesn't show the value of any AngularJS local variables. Hover shows nothing and right click 'Evaluate in console' throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined`

Is there someway to see the values of variables inside AngularJS during debugging?

Thanks.

[Edit for Bruno]
This is the code where context is lost, (angular.js (1.4.8)):

```
function createShortMethods(names) {
   forEach(arguments, function(name) {
      $http[name] = function(url, config) {
         return $http(extend({}, config || {}, {
            method: name,
            url: url
         }));
      };
   });
}
```

Stepping into `$http.get` (above) neither `url` nor `config` have values in the debugger. `url` probably has a value as the REST API is accessed over the network.

Tried Batarang, it does not want to work with Angular 1.4.8

[Update]
Looks like this is related to Angular's use of strict mode, I'll have to work around that.

Thanks to everyone for their time & thoughts.

Comment: It'll be easier to get help if you show the problematic piece of your code (controller + view), including the line where you set the break point.

Comment: Doubtful, it's a problem with Chrome Developer Tools debugger and Angular, but here you go.

Comment: I don't follow. If I step *into* `$http.get` and `url` and `config` are function parameters I should be able to inspect their values in the local (function) context. That is, `url` and `config` are in the current stack frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782069/how-to-debug-angular-javascript-code

Comment: @Bruno, not a duplicate, other SO questions of this nature are about debugging applications using Angular, this question is about debugging AngularJS itself (inside AngularJS). The problem is that Angular declares strict which disables looking at local variables inside Angular.

Comment: Just to be sure: You are on the line `return $http(extend({} ...` and you don't have a minified version of Angular? Strict mode doesn't have anything to do with debugging.

Comment: @zeroflagL no, that I'm not certain of. My (limited) understanding of strict mode was that you can't walk the call stack so `.caller` and `.arguments` won't evaluate. No?

Comment: Strict mode is about the language. The debugger works with the engine. It has no such limitations. Without further information your question is hard to answer. Maybe a screenshot can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). It is for debugging angular applications.
[ng-inspector for AngularJS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en) can also help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a breakpoint before the `$http.get(XXX)`and then in the Chrome's console you can inspect variables by writing their names.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to debug is *inside* Angular, I really need visibility.

Comment: have you checked the value of the url variable? if you write $http it return the $http function.