# Debug AngularJS code

Tags: angularjs

How do I Debug AngularJS code written in .cshtml file, I'm using Visual Studio Express for Web 2015.
I tried using "debugger;" in my code but it did not work and I cannot my Javascript code to a separate .js file.

Comment: The answer to this question really depends on what you mean by "writing code in a cshtml file."  You might even want to re-evaluate your tech stack if you're writing razor side by side with angular.

Comment: You may refer to previous post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782069/how-to-debug-angular-javascript-code

Comment: I don't know why using "debugger" in my cshtml file did not work at first hand, but when I restarted my Visual studio  it worked fine.