# Asp.net Core 2 - Angular template (One Solution)

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have some problems to start the project after downloading the ASP.NET Core with Angular One soluton template.
I start it with iis express but the client app don't start.
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core
Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned here https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Getting-Started-Angular

Comment: Yes, but even if the angular app is on the same project of backend it don't run...

Comment: What are you trying to run? Host ?

Comment: It start only from console "npm start". Can I start angular app and backend both in visual studio IIS Express?

Comment: You should run Angular app by using npm start. It cannot be run like backend code using visual studio

Comment: @viveknuna is right. When you run your merged project with Visual Studio, you should be able to see your host app on http://example.com/swagger. I mean you need to add /swagger at the end of the url.

Comment: In order to run angular app, you need to open command prompt and run "npm start" in the root directory of your host project and visit it on http://localhost:4200.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ismcagdas

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run/debug angular project from VS. Because the Angular project is running with using Angular-CLI. For debugging check following links.

1. [How to debug Angular JavaScript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782069/how-to-debug-angular-javascript-code)
2. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications

Try Visual Studio Code and add the [Chrome debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) extension and add a configuration to launch.json something like this.

```
{  
    "version": "0.2.0",  
    "configurations": [{  
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",  
        "type": "chrome",  
        "request": "launch",  
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",  
        "sourceMaps": true,  
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",  
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {  
            "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"  
        }  
    }]  
}
```

You can also refer this document for more details.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Answer (score 0):

Merged solution is a structure where angular and host project files are located in the same directory. that doesn't mean host and client app start within IIS Express. So you cannot run Angular in IIS Express. Just run `npm start`.